# Pixel values of bitmap image after scaling in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3, image-processing, flex4, pixel

I'm trying to analyze how scaling works internally in ActionScript.

I created a small scenario:

1. created a 2 X 2 jpg image and imported in flex. Image has 4 pixels now
2. created a bitmap and used getPixel(x, y) and printed out values.

   ```
   Values of bitmap 2 X 2
   ╔══════════╦══════════╗
   ║ 16777215 ║ 16777215 ║
   ╠══════════╬══════════╣
   ║ 16777215 ║ 16777215 ║
   ╚══════════╩══════════╝
   ```
3. Now I scaled bitmap to scaleX = 2 and printed out pixel values.

   ```
   for (var x:int =0; x < original.width; x = x+1)
   {
       for (var y:int = 0; y < original.height; y = y+1)
       {
           tempUnit = original.bitmapData.getPixel(x,y);
           outputString1 = outputString1 + tempUnit.toString() + '\t';
       }
       outputString1 = outputString1  + '\r\n';
   }
   ```

   Values of bitmap after scaling

   ```
   Values of bitmap
   ╔══════════╦══════════╗
   ║ 16777215 ║ 16777215 ║
   ║ 16777215 ║ 16777215 ║
   ╠══════════╬══════════╣
   ║        0 ║        0 ║
   ║        0 ║        0 ║
   ╚══════════╩══════════╝
   ```

What values does pixel at position (2,0), (2,1), (3,0), (3,1) take? Does it not take average values of existing pixels?

I took just these 4 pixels to analyze. I concluded that he X and Y axis unit is being changed after scaling with respect to display Object.

I'm new to ActionScript and image processing. Please point me in right direction.

Answer (score 3):

BitmapDatas do not scale when you scale a Bitmap. Look at Bitmap as a scalable wrapper for BitmapData. So, for a BitmapData you should not try getting pixels out of its bounds.

Comment: So i need to manually change values of pixels in bitmapData? I expected to accomplish pixel replication or average bi linear interpolation of neighboring pixels. 
I think i'll manully write functions to accomplish them, flash wont do these underneath.

Comment: Not exactly, you can perform a `BitmapData.draw()` to get your bilinear interpolation. You have to provide a transformation matrix to draw a certain object onto a BitmapData. There are mor efunctions there to achieve such a goal.